# Conflicts with jQuery and the ToolkitScirptManager?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, jquery

It just started experimenting with the ajax.net ToolkitScirptManager and it works fine but then I realized that it is breaking my ajax calls I'm doing using the jQuery library.  I'm guessing that it is the issue with the $ symbol, does anyone have anythoughts on how to use both libraries.

I don't want to use jquery's noconflict mode because we use other jquery plugins that I'm afraid won't work.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I've used both successfully on a project in the past, but I have also experienced instances where there seemed to be issues.  The noconflict mode in jquery won't help you here since the MS ajax libraries don't use the "$" by itself (its alway $get() or some such).

I think the root of your problem may lie in the sort of controls your using from the toolkit (Update panels are just pure evil no two ways about it) and what kind of crazy stuff they do when the page is loaded.  I had an issue once which was causing libraries referenced with a  tag not to load, and I was able to work around it by moving the script tags for the items that were missing to the end of the markup (sounds strange, I know).

Wish I could offer more tangible advice.

Answer (score 0):

The $ symbol is one of the issues depending on how you coded javascript, but most of the problems are in the interaction between UpdatePanel and Jquery.
A nice post is shown here:

http://weblogs.asp.net/hajan/archive/2010/10/07/make-them-to-love-each-other-asp-net-ajax-updatepanels-amp-javascript-jquery-functions.aspx

Note:For jquery UI I use this reference link:

http://blog.roonga.com.au/2009/07/using-jquery-ui-dialog-with-aspnet-and.html